# ¿Como realizar este menu de pestañas en HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo esta imagen, donde me piden replicar en HTML, CSS, Javascript, Jquery, etc. Estoy comenzando en la programación web y mi duda surge en como se llama este efecto, donde yo tengo una serie de pestañas con vista previa como en la siguiente imagen, y al dar click este me desplegara la vista completa de la pagina web, y asi con cada una. No se como se llama, para poder investigarlo y documentarme acerca de esto, para realizar mi proyecto.

Les agradeceria bastante si alguien me ayudara sobre como puedo realizarlo o en todo caso darme una idea de lo que puedo investigar para realizar este efecto.

Gracias.

Comment: No se como se llama ese efecto, ¿mostrar / ocultar?
Puedes lograrlo simplemente con HTML con las etiquetas: `details` y `summary`. Para tener algo como lo de la imagen tendrás que añadir mas HTML y CSS. Para cada cuadro en concreto busca como hacer un "modal sin javascript".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No te voy a decir como se hace entero. Pero para poder empezar puedes aprender mucho en esta página https://www.w3schools.com/

no sé si lo sabes pero cada recuadro es un 
entonces en los estilo tienes que poner algo así:

```
<head><style>
div{width:100px;height:100px;border-radius: 10px;}
</style></head>
<body>
<div>
<div style="width:50%;"><div/><div style="width:50%;"></div>
</div>
<body>
```

esto para empezar ya te digo de antemano que en el div tendrás que poner más cosas

Comment: Por favor evitemos responder a preguntas mal planteadas pues es seguro terminen cerradas